# SharePoint 2010: How to troubleshoot a feature designed to replace the SmallSearchInputBox?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have been trying to create a feature which replaces the SmallSearchInputBox delegate in SharePoint 2010.

I have a new control which I placed in ~/controltemplates and created an element and feature xml.

In the debug mode of VS2010, I can see the site collection feature and activate it but nothing changes to the search area. I also tried farm scope but no difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the Sequence attribute of your delegate control lower than the default SharePoint control? I guess SP uses a sequence of 50 or 100 for the search box, did you try a value lower than that?
Otherwise SP doesn't show your control, but the SP control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had set the sequence to 20, 10 even 1 but no difference :-(